# TPL.Dataflow message processing timeout?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Using .NET TPL DataFlow blocks.
Is there any way to timeout the processing of a message?

e.g.

lets say I have a `BufferBlock<T>`, is it possible to link that to another block that processes one message at a time (`MaxDegreeOfParallellism` 1) and force a timeout if the processing runs for too long?
Or is it even possible to do using the BufferBlock only?

I suspect I can use a cancellation token somehow and a delay, but not sure how this would be done.
Also, how expensive would such timeout be? would it add much overhead to the message processing time?

Comment: I don't think there's a built in timeout. you can create a block with one if you only want to filter those items, and not just remove to make room for others.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by “forcing a timeout”? Are you trying to [cancel a non-cancelable operation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/10/05/how-do-i-cancel-non-cancelable-async-operations.aspx)? (I'm talking about your processing code, not anything in dataflow.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many methods of `BufferBlock<T>` do accept `CancellationToken`, and I believe that would be the proper way of timing out an operation. E.g.:

```
var cts = new CancellationTokenSource(5000); // cancel in 5s 
// Alternatively: cts.CancelAfter(5000);

try 
{
    var output = await bufferBlock.ReceiveAsync(cts.Token);
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    // check if ex is OperationCanceledException,
    // which could be wrapped with AggregateException 
}
```

IMO, the only way of evaluating its efficiency would be to run some profiling tests.

**[UPDATE]** Based upon the comments, if you're looking to time-out the pipeline processing, you can probably do that when you construct your `ActionBlock` object and provide it with an instance of `ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions`. At that point, you can supply [`DataflowBlockOptions.CancellationToken`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.dataflowblockoptions.cancellationtoken%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and use it in the same way as described above. Also, you could pass a `CancellationToken` into `LinkTo` as a part of `DataflowLinkOptions`.

Once you've provided the pipeline with a `CancellationToken`, you can track the status of [`ActionBlock.Completion`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160304%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)/`TransformBlock.Completion`, which is a `Task`, so you can `await` it and catch a cancellation exception, or use `ContinueWith` with it (if that's what you mean under *some way to tell if the "processing" of the message times out*).

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this myself and would be interested to know whether it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks, that above code will however cancel if the receive times out, I need some way to tell if the "processing" of the message times out. but mabe that is possible is some similar way, if I pipe the message through my processor and forward it to another block

Comment: @RogerAlsing, I think so. You could probably utilize `token.Register` and/or `CreateLinkedTokenSource` for that. Maybe you could show a sketch of your processing code.

Comment: The code that should timeout is located on the highlighted line here: https://github.com/rogeralsing/Pigeon/blob/master/Pigeon/Actor/Mailbox.cs#L34  I'm using the bufferblock as an observable there, but this is in no way a requirement, I just want to invoke "onNext" once I receive a message from the bufferblock, and if it executes for more than x time then throw